# Stored procedure execution order

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Thanks for your time, is there a way to execute the create database part of the statement before the use database name?

I guess I could create 2 set and execute statements but there must be a better way ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Master] 
    @DBNAME NVARCHAR(50) 
AS 
    DECLARE @CODE NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @CODE = 'CREATE DATABASE '+@DBNAME+'; USE '+@DBNAME

    EXEC SP_Executesql @CODE
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Creating a database in a stored procedure does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply. This is part of a much wider stored procedure. It creates a database a database from a directory on my pc.

Comment: Apologies im fairly new to the forum & SQL. Thanks for the guidance i have updated the tags.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How should a database be created, if not in a stored procedure?

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is wide open to injection attacks. *Never* inject unsantised values into dynamic statements. Properly quote your objects, using `QUOTENAME` and *parametrise* them (don't use `EXEC (@SQL)` which doesn't allow parametrisation).

Comment: *"How should a database be created, if not in a stored procedure?"* What's wrong with just running `CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase;`?

Comment: On a side note, be aware that after you execute a dynamic SQL batch with a `USE` statement, the database context reverts back to the original db context after the execute statement completes.